CRT impedance-matching-transformer design questions
UPDATE:
I'm going to be honest, I am in way over my head here. I don't have the necessary math skills and analog design experience to make this elegant. I just want this to work at all. If anyone can link me to a transformer that might work, please let me know.
TLDR:
I am trying to custom design a transformer to fix an impedance mismatch between a CRT chassis and a CRT yoke. What size and shape ferrite core should I get? What size wire do I need for the primary and secondary winding? How many windings do I need in absolute numbers? I know that I need a ~4.5:1 winding ratio and for the transformer to support 100va at 15.7khz. How many windings do I need, at what wire gauge? Should I consider an autotransformer?
Context
For context, I have obtained a junk Gateway EV700 CRT  monitor (manufactured by LiteOn) in poor condition. As an experiment, I decided to see if I could modify it with a "universal"   chassis board from Aliexpress . I naively attempted to hook up all the wires of the chassis to the tube as is, but I got horrible buzzing noises (not to be confused with 15khz whine) from the flyback transformer and no raster. Upon disconnecting the horizontal deflection (but leaving the vertical in place), I was able to obtain a horizontally collapsed raster. By all indications, there is a severe impedance mismatch between the flyback and the horizontal windings in the yoke.
The impedance mismatch is on the order of 20:1 between the chassis (flyback) and the yoke. I must match the impedance by some means. According to my research, the most practical way for me to do that would be to use a transformer. Alternatives could include changing yoke windings or using an RLC network. I am opting to use the transformer method.
Chassis and Yoke Characteristics
I am assuming my "universal" CRT chassis board I obtained from Aliexpress expects a CRT TV yoke with horizontal deflection winding specs similar to these:

note: in my impedance calculation, I am assuming capacitance to be 0

Proxy TV Chassis Expected Yoke specs (source)

resistance: 16.313 ohm
inductance: 3.595 mH @10khz
impedance: 226 ohm
source: https://crtdatabase.com/crts/curtis-mathes/curtis-mathes-cm19001
manufactured by Samsung

I could not find nor fully measure my exact CRT monitor horizontal deflection winding specs, so I am using the following as a proxy:
Proxy Monitor Horizontal Yoke Specs (load)

resistance: 0.584 ohm (my CRT measured 0.5 ohm)
inductance 0.18427 mH @ 10khz
impedance 11.6 ohm
source: https://crtdatabase.com/crts/viewsonic/viewsonic-e771
note: this monitor is of the same diagonal size as mine (17" total) and is also manufactured by LiteOn

Transformer Notes
I am trying to obtain a transformer with the following specs. However, I have been unable to find one for sale anywhere with the right specifications. Audio and SMPS transformers are generally too small and have the wrong winding ratios. Power transformers use a laminated steel core, which is grossly inadquate for 15khz operation, despite meeting the other specs. At this point, I am prepared to have to order one custom made or DIY it.
Transformer Specifications

winding ratio ~4.5:1
≥ 100VA power capacity
ferrite core (to support 15.7khz operation)

Conclusion
If I need to DIY the transformer, what size and shape ferrite core should I use, what gauge of wire do I need for the windings, and how many windings do I need on the primary and the secondary in absolute terms? Alternatively, what are some decent but cheap places to get custom transformers, like in China or something?
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

you may find that a tape-wound transformer (toroidal or r-core) has the bandwidth you need.

If you need to DIY the transformer,  perhaps instead DIY the yoke?

SMPS transformers from e-bike chargers or old ATX power supplies could match. I have one in my recycling box marked LPJ050003330 which has the required parameters. However, it would be just luck if the picture is acceptable.

At this point, I'm just trying to see if I can get it to work at all. I'd try rewinding the yoke, but I can't seem to even get it off the tube and it's not designed to be taken apart non destructively. I figured that if the inductance is correct at the fundamental (or a nearby frequency) and the transformer has a sufficiently wide bandwidth, I wouldn't have to worry to much about the exact transformer inductance, because it's the windings ratio that I care about, right?

Jens, any chance I could buy that transformer from you?
